# Django Rest, OrderingFilter using ForeignKey field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest's OrderingFilter to order my API endpoint results (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#orderingfilter)

like so:

```
/endpoint?ordering=-id
```

Is it possible to give it a foreign key field to order by?

like:

```
/endpoint?ordering=myfk__id
```

Trying the above doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `ordering_fields` in your `view`. So your field should look like:

```
ordering_fields = ('myfk__id',)
```

EDIT:

Looks like this is not currently allowed in DRF. See [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1005). That being said, that site includes a snippet of some code you can use to implement it. Basically, use the filter code posted to subclass the `OrderingFilter` and use that as your filter instead.

Comment: I had,     ```ordering_fields = '__all__'```

Comment: added above  stackOverFlowMin15Chars .

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite list method of ListModelMixin, then you can use all ORM ordering.

```
class ViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):  

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        params = request.GET.get('ordering', '')
        if params:
            ordering = [param.strip() for param in params.split(',')]
            queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)
        
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```